# How to check Jquery is already loaded in the page in xslt

Tags: jquery, xslt

I need to check whether the Jquery.JS is loaded ,if not then load it. The below code works fine in my .aspx file, but i need to implement the same in my .xslt also.Its giving error while running in the xslt,

ASPX working code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="JQuery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">\x3C/script>')
  </script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("hi");
    });
  </script>
```

If i write the same aspx code in xslt,its throwing "Tag was not closed" error

XSLT code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 **line1**     (window.jQuery ===  undefined) and document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/js/jquery.js"'))
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("hi");
    });
  </script>
```

Errors:
Expected ; at line1 .

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
**UPDATED**
The below code works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      if(typeof jQuery=="undefined")
      {
      document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/js/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
      }     
    </script>
```

Comment: don't use the `document.write` for script registration. it is not always success. better way is `document.createElement` and append it to the document head. [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8722371/880434)

Answer (score 2):

**The problem is in the XSLT code that you haven't shown to us**.

I tried and couldn't reproduce the reported error -- this transformation is executed without any problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <script type="text/javascript">  **line1**     (window.jQuery ===  undefined) and document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/js/jquery.js"')) </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">     $(document).ready(function() {     alert("hi");     });   </script>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on any XML document (not used), the result is as expected**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  **line1**     (window.jQuery ===  undefined) and document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/js/jquery.js"')) </script>
<script type="text/javascript">     $(document).ready(function() {     alert("hi");     });   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try following code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        (function() {var jq = document.createElement('script');jq.type = 'text/javascript';jq.async = true;jq.src = '/js/jquery.js';var s = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(jq, s);})();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Vani: don't use the `document.write` for script registration. it is not always success. better way is `document.createElement` and append it to the document head.